# Self Organizing Map (SOM)

Tags: data-mining, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

How do you use SOM as a supervised learning technique? Which approach can be added to SOM to turn it to supervised learning?

Comment: I miss the point of using SOMs in supervised setting, since then a usual NN is implied instead

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with k-means: If you add class information on top of it, you get the learning vector quantization (LVQ). On the other hand, if you impose a topology on the means (force them on an elastic net), you get the self-organizing map.

Now, the two are independent: you can enrich k-means by both class information and topology (i.e. impose a topology on LVQ) and obtain a supervised SOM.